# How to use replace `Proxy :: Proxy a` with `type MyType a = Int` with `a` as phantom type

Tags: haskell, type-inference

While playing with types in Haskell, I came up with the following:

```
class    MyType a    where typeVal :: Proxy a -> Int
instance MyType Int  where typeVal _ = 1
instance MyType Char where typeVal _ = 2

g :: MyType a => Int -> Proxy a -> Int
g x p = x + typeVal p
```

This works as expected. Then, I got the idea that perhaps I can have the function return a custom type in place of having to pass in a `Proxy`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

type R a = Int

f :: forall a. MyType a => Int -> R a
f x = x + typeVal (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't. I get the error:

```
Could not deduce (MyType a0)
from the context (MyType a)
  bound by the type signature for f :: MyType a => Int -> R a
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘f’:
  f :: forall a. MyType a => Int -> R a
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘f’: f :: MyType a => Int -> R a
```

I don't want to enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes` because I don't think there is any ambiguity. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type synonyms are completely equivalent to their expansions: `R Int ~ R Bool ~ R Char ~ Int`. So, you are actually using the type

```
f :: forall a. MyType a => Int -> Int
```

which is inherently ambiguous, since the type variable `a` is used only in the constraint.

In particular, if `T` is a `data` or `newtype`, then the compiler can simplify a type equality constraint `T a ~ T b` and deduce `a ~ b`.

With type families, this is no longer true since they can be non injective (albeit there is a GHC 8.0 extension which can deal properly with injectivity).

With type synomyms, this is also not true in general. Given `T a ~ T b` we expand the synonym `T` before proceeding further: if `a` and `b` disappear in this step nothing can be inferred about them.

Comment: Does this mean that I must use `data` or `newtype` here?

Comment: @rityzmon I think so, for the moment.

Comment: Thanks. So I'm confused then. Why would the compiler allow a type synonym like `type R a = Int` when the `a` cannot be used?

Comment: It's not very useful, but why forbid it?

Comment: @rityzmon What do you mean? `R Char` can be used, as `R b` can be, but they both mean `Int`. The fact that `b` is not determined is another issue.

Comment: @augustss Because `a` cannot possibly serve any purpose. If it wasn't allowed, I probably would've figured out why my code didn't work.

Comment: @rityzmon But a signature like `C a => Proxy a -> R a` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Would you also forbid `f a = 5`?  The `a` cannot serve any purpose.

Comment: @rityzmon Also note that the type error is telling: it tells that the `a` variable is ambiguous w.r.t. the constraints. It explicitly says that this is a problem of the signature, and not the actual code.

Comment: The real problem, IMO, is that Haskell beginners are learning about type synonyms. Type synonyms are rarely actually useful to beginners, even though they tend to expect them to be.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, you're right. My central mistake in this question was that I thought the `a` in `R a` of `f :: forall a. MyType a => Int -> R a` could be meaningfully used in the implementation just like a *phantom type*. But apparently not. It is just dropped when the synonym is substituted.